# IIS 8.5 Custom Fields breaks LogParser 2.2

Tags: sql-server, iis, iis-8.5, logparser

So LogParser has been a tool that I have used to load IIS Logs into a SQL Server database on a daily basis.

The problem is that if you use the new IIS 8.5 custom fields it will break LogParser with this sort of error:
Unknown field  found in #Fields directive

I have looked at the various formats and don't see anything that is very interesting.  It would appear that I would have to write a COM object to read the IIS file.

Looks like I am going to be creating my own loader for the IIS Logs unless anyone has any other ideas?

I wish the LogParser code was released to GitHub.

Comment: There is almost no possibility to see the code, and publishing your wishes above is useless. Import IIS log files directly to SQL Server and you can then use standard SQL to parse the fields.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the IISW3C format, correct? What happens if you use the W3C format instead?

Comment: The names are different in the W3C format and I think it is missing some values that I am interested in.  Additionally the W3C input format doesn't include the check point feature.

I am surprised about the comment from Lex Li (a Microsoft MVP?).

In the past logging using ODBC from IIS directly resulted in increased latency.  Haven't tested it in a long time.

I have used LogParser to load IIS logs for years.  There are a ton of features in it that are really useful.  I don't use the "stock" table.

As always opinions will vary...